Как в API VK получить список лайкнутых постов?
Всем привет, облазил документацию апишки вк и не нашел там нужного метода. Вот лайкаю я посты в ленте, как мне теперь получить список лайкнутых постов?
Использую Python и библиотеку vk_api, но к вопросу это наверное не имеет отношения.
